# Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

Tags: python, pip

ando tratando de trabajar con Scrappy en python 3. Tratando de instalar por medio del "PIP" la librería, al principio me mandaba un error ("Microsoft 14.0 is required") y lo pude solucionar, pero ahora me lanza otro error, el del titulo.
Estuve leyendo que necesito instalar "libxml2" igual con un pip, pero no funcionó. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: La instalación de ciertas librerías, en particular  las que incluyen código C/C++ suele ser bastante problemáticas, particularmente en `Windows`. Si este fuera el caso, una opción podría ser descargar e instalar desde la lista de binarios no oficiales: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Ya lo he intentado, pero me sigue apareciendo lo mismo :c. Aun así, muchísimas gracias.